# how do I change the location of the httpd.conf for Apache on windows?

Tags: windows, apache, httpd.conf

I am working on setting up a load balancing cluster on windows server 2012 and have a shared drive where I want the configuration files for Apache to exist at. This way each member of the LB can load the exact same config files. How do I change where the config file is located independently of where the ServerRoot is?

Comment: wow.. That's a good one lol.

Comment: I know I have been coming up empty on google searches...

Comment: @Du6e, ? What's a good one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start the Apache process with the `-d` parameter and give your alternative `ServerRoot` as an argument, though I'd imagine it would be a much better idea for you to use some mechanism to sync the files locally to each server.

Also read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex, as it's advised if you're running from a networked file system.

If you just want to specify the main config file, start the process with the `-f` parameter and the path to the config file as an argument.

Comment: Is there a way to specify just the config file not the server root? Let the config file say where the root is?

Comment: okay for anyone else dealing with this here is the finalized knowledge on it... delete your existing service with "sc delete Apache2.4" then run "E:\apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k install -n "Apache2.4" -f "G:\configs\httpd.conf"   and that will create the service with the custom file.