# How can I change the default apache httpd.conf file location

Tags: windows, apache, httpd.conf

Default location of apache httpd configuration file httpd.conf is apache-http-root\conf folder. How can I change this location to load the config file from somewhere else?

Comment: This question was asked already on SO, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328702/how-do-i-change-the-location-of-the-httpd-conf-for-apache-on-windows

Comment: and probably this question is better located on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install apache Httpd as windows service, you need to run the following command:

```
httpd.exe -k install
```

If you use this command the service will be called Apache2.4 and the configuration will be assumed to be conf\httpd.conf.

If you need to specify the name of the service you want to install, use the following command. You have to do this if you have several different service installations of Apache on your computer. If you specify a name during the install, you have to also specify it during any other -k operation.

```
httpd.exe -k install -n "MyServiceName"
```

If you need to have specifically named configuration files for different services, you must use this:

```
httpd.exe -k install -n "MyServiceName" -f "c:\files\my.conf"
```

If you use this command the service will be called MyServiceName and the configuration will be assumed to be c:\files\my.conf.

Source: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html